# How to create Polyline using react-google-maps library

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot Polyline between 4 GPS coordinates using react-google-maps library. Nothing is rendering on the map

```
import React from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow,Polyline } from 'react-google-maps';


class googleMapComponent extends React.Component {
```

//Higher order components: withGoogleMap is employed as a function call. This fucntion returns another component defination which is later mounted in render

```
 // maintain a refernce to a map inside the component, so that
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
            map:null
        }
    }

    mapMoved(){
        console.log('mapMoved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.map.getCenter()))
    }

    mapLoaded(map){
        //console.log('mapLoaded: ' + JSON.stringify(map.getCenter()))
        if(this.state.map !==null)
            return

        this.setState({
            map:map
        })
    }

    zoomchanged(){
        console.log('mapZoomed: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.map.getZoom()))
    }
    handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
        this.setState({
            markers: this.state.markers.map(marker => {
                if (marker === targetMarker) {
                    return {
                        ...marker,
                        showInfo: true,
                    };
                }
                return marker;
            }),
        });
    }

    handleMarkerClose(targetMarker) {
        this.setState({
            markers: this.state.markers.map(marker => {
                if (marker === targetMarker) {
                    return {
                        ...marker,
                        showInfo: false,
                    };
                }
                return marker;
            }),
        });
    }

    render() {

        const markers= [
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.05298766, -112.0837566),
                showInfo: false,
                infoContent: false,
            },
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.21698848, -112.0567275),
                showInfo: false,
                infoContent: false,
            },
        ]
        const lineCoordinates= [
        {coordinate:  new google.maps.LatLng(36.05298766, -112.0837566)},
        {coordinate:  new google.maps.LatLng(36.0529832169413, -112.083731889724)},
        {coordinate:  new google.maps.LatLng(36.0529811214655, -112.083720741793)},
        {coordinate:  new google.maps.LatLng(36.0529811214655, -112.083720741793)},
    ]

        return (
            <GoogleMap
                ref={this.mapLoaded.bind(this)}
                onDragEnd={this.mapMoved.bind(this)}
                onZoomChanged={this.zoomchanged.bind(this)}
                defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
                defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            >
                {markers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <Marker
                        position={marker.position}
                        title="click on it Sir..!!"
                        defaultPosition={this.props.center}
                        style={{height: '2xpx', width: '2px'}}
                    />
                ))}

                {lineCoordinates.map((polyline,index)=>(
                <Polyline
                    defaultPosition={this.props.center}
                    path= {polyline.coordinate}
                    geodesic= {true}
                    strokeColor= {#FF0000}
                    strokeOpacity= {1.0}
                    strokeWeight= {2}
                />

            </GoogleMap>

        )
    }
}
export default withGoogleMap(googleMapComponent);
```

Any suggestion on it will be helpful. If the library does not support this functionality. I can swtich the library too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the mapping function, are you creating a new polyline for each set of coordinates? Looking at [the Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple), the polyline takes an array of objects as a path argument. google-maps-react is just a wrapper around that API, so you should be able to create your polyline just by passing in the array of objects as the path. Currently, you're trying to generate a bunch of polyline objects based on tiny coordinate fragments.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Example:

```
render() {
    const pathCoordinates = [
        { lat: 36.05298765935, lng: -112.083756616339 },
        { lat: 36.2169884797185, lng: -112.056727493181 }
    ];
    return (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        >
            {/*for creating path with the updated coordinates*/}
            <Polyline
                path={pathCoordinates}
                geodesic={true}
                options={{
                    strokeColor: "#ff2527",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.75,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    icons: [
                        {
                            icon: lineSymbol,
                            offset: "0",
                            repeat: "20px"
                        }
                    ]
                }}
            />
        </GoogleMap>
    );
}
```

Comment: yes, it is working. You can see the example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vaa779812GY&t=18s)

Comment: Spent a while trying to figure out why this wasn't working for me, turns out the `path` needs to be set within `options`. Maybe this is something that changed at some point.

Comment: Not really @IanW. Maybe you can set the `path` in the `options`, but the reason you thought this wasn't working is that previously **`strokeOpacity`** was set to `0.0`. Setting it to something more visible works.

Comment: @JayantBhawal That wasn't the issue in my case; I had `strokeOpacity` set to 1.

Comment: Aha. Another thing may have been that Lat and Lng values were swapped, so it would have been working but you wouldn't be seeing them. This, and strokeOpacity were the two things that made me think it wasn't working at different points of time. Even then this might not have solved your problem, but maybe it'll help someone else looking around.

Comment: It saves my day :)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler example to show just one polyline being drawn:

```
<GoogleMap defaultZoom={7} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.897, lng: 151.144 }}>
    <Polyline path={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}/>
</GoogleMap>
```

Entire snippet for anyone unclear about the correct imports and setup **(with recompose)**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polyline
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={7} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.897, lng: 151.144 }}>
    <Polyline path={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}/>
  </GoogleMap>
));

ReactDOM.render(<MyMapComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Same example as above, **without recompose**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Polyline
} from "react-google-maps";

const InternalMap = props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={7} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.897, lng: 151.144 }}>
    <Polyline
      path={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
);

const MapHoc = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(InternalMap));

const MyMapComponent = props => (
  <MapHoc
    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyMapComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```